# How do I save a picture from the gallery in the application?

Tags: android, gridview, save, adapter

I have a GridView, which element consists of a photo and text. When you click "add" it is possible to upload a photo from the gallery and fill in the text.
Q: How to make sure that these data are stored in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing on a disk cache can help you.

This way even when user closes your app and comes back to it later, the images will be picked from cache!

Warning, Android stores bitmap in both the memory and disk cache when storing in disk cache:

> Components like GridView with larger datasets can easily fill up a memory cache.

Storing using content providers can be effective way to store such images. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)